# How to calculate the amount of a dependent variable that was owing to an independent variable

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, marketing

I have run a regression analysis on some radio marketing activity and its effect on the number of website users, however, I was wondering if there was a way to then use this to calculate the amount of website users was owing to the radio activity?

E.g. of the 20,000 website sessions seen in a month, 400 were owing to the radio activity.